# C printf output to variable

Tags: c, libc

I am trying to a loop packet [bytes] and to put the result into the variable, however I stucked for few hours to put it into variable.

This is what is working, just outputting it. I've tried strcat, strcpy and sprintf to put the output into a variable and no success. Suggest me please what to do, cause Im lost, thanks :)

```
i = 54;
do {
 printf("%c", Buffer[i]);
 i++;
} while(i != Size);
```

Comment: Let's see the other code that is not working

Comment: `sprintf(OutputBuffer,"%c",Buffer[i])` doesn't work?  Do you want to store the string in a variable, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Then Im trying to print it and without success, some strange char or even blank.. Why strcat(str,Buffer[i]); does not work?

Comment: Is `Buffer[i]` valid null terminated C-string?

Comment: sometimes yes, sometimes not, the input packet is always different

Comment: Be more clear in your questions, inform the platform and environment where he is developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of pieces of this code should help but you have asked very unclear question and it's hard to understand what indeed you're trying to do.

BTW as you can see `Buffer` here is not initialized (actually all of them as others depends on `Buffer`. It was intent to get some data to output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int Size = 100;
    unsigned char Buffer[Size];
    unsigned char OutBuffer[Size];
    unsigned char PrnBuffer[Size*3];

    /* I have understanding you tried to output chars to OutBuffer but
       you just need to iterate OutBuffer bytes the same way... */
    int i = 54;
    int j = 0;
    do {
        sprintf(&(OutBuffer[j]), "%c", Buffer[i]);
        /* But why simply not outBuffer[j] = Buffer[i]; ?? */
        i++;
        j++;
    } while(i != Size);

    /* And now print this trash... */
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(&(PrnBuffer[i*3]), "%02x ", OutBuffer[i]);
    }
    printf("%d: %s\n", j, PrnBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```